# Delete sqs queue based on 'CreatedTimestamp'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

Similar to question [Bulk delete sqs queues using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332743/bulk-delete-sqs-queues-using-boto3), I now want to delete queues based on 'CreatedTimestamp'. If the created time (in epoch time) is before a specific epoch timestamp, it should be deleted.

I tried to write something similar to answer given in the earlier post but I am not sure if I need to to loop again to check the created time.

```
client = boto3.client('sqs')

timestamp = '1645747200'


def delete_sqs_queues (event, context):
    response = client.list_queues()
    
    for sqs_url in response['QueueUrls']:
        get_att = client.get_queue_attributes(
            QueueUrl=sqs_url,
            AttributeNames=['CreatedTimestamp']
            )
```

Can I directly compare the CreatedTimestamp with a variable or do I need another for loop to iterate over the CreatedTimestamps?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `CreatedTimestamp` for each queue, thus you don't have to iterate again:

```
    for sqs_url in response['QueueUrls']:
        get_att = client.get_queue_attributes(
            QueueUrl=sqs_url,
            AttributeNames=['CreatedTimestamp']
            )
        
        queue_timestamp = get_att['Attributes']['CreatedTimestamp']
        print(queue_timestamp)

        # for example
        if queue_timestamp < timestamp:
            print(f'Delete {sqs_url} because of {queue_timestamp}')
```